# Easiest way to scale Mongo with limited resources?

Tags: mongodb, scalability

I have a web server (40gig hd, 1 gig ram) that runs Mongo and a Rails application.

The Mongo DB is a document store of Twitter tweets and users, which has several million records. I perform map-reduce queries on the data to extract things like most common hashtags, words, mentions etc (very standard stuff). The meta-data of each tweet is already stored, so the map-reduce is really as efficient as a single collect.

However, since it is run on a (fairly) large dataset, it can't be done in real-time anymore - for example I have a report generator that works out a whole bunch of these map-reduces in a row and takes about 2 minutes for 20 thousand tweets.

What is the quickest, cheapest way to scale mongo, especially in map-reduce performance? I can set up an additional server and split the load, but wonder if I should use sharding, replication or both? Sharding may be overkill for this situation.

Would love some input on my mysql-mongo connection. mysql contains twitter profiles that store twitter ids for each profile. each time a map reduce is done, it collects all IDs to be fed as options into the mapreduce ie:

```
@profile_tweet_ids = current_profile_tweet_ids # array of ids
@daily_trend = TwitterTweet.daily_trend :query => {:twitter_id => {"$in" => @profile_tweet_ids}}
```

The mapreduce function in TwitterTweet looks like:

```
def daily_trend(options={})
  options[:out] = "daily_trend"

  map = %Q( function(){
                if (this.created_at != null)
                {
                  emit(this.created_at.toDateString(), 1);
                }
            })

  result = collection.map_reduce(map, standard_reduce, options)
  normalize_results(result)
end
```

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing simple counts, sums, uniques etc, you may be able to avoid using map-reduce completely. You can use the $inc operator to get most of the stuff that you need in real-time.
I have explained this in detail in my blog post on [real-time analytics with MongoDB](http://samarthbhargava.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/real-time-analytics-with-mongodb/).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your use case is more in the lines of online stream / event processing. 
You can use mongo or other databases / caching product to store reference data, and an event processing framework for receiving and processing the events. There are a few tools that can help you with that - out the back of my head here are a few: Twitter Storm, Apache S4, [GigaSpaces XAP](http://bit.ly/JzFVJy) (disclaimer - I work for GigaSpaces) and GridGain.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the cloud services like MongoLab.. Depends on your definition of cheap though..

Answer (score 0):

The answer regarding using operators rather than MapReduce has merits, and may be far more beneficial to your efforts to get real time responses.  Map Reduce on mongodb does not lend itself to yielding real time responses.

Further to that, you may also benefit from the new aggregation framework (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Aggregation+Framework), once that is available in the next release.

To answer the more general question about how to scale out MapReduce, adding a new server may not help if you are simply going to add it as a secondary, as a secondary it will not have the capability to store your M/R results in a collection, so inline is your only option.  If you do not need to store results in a collection then this is your easiest way forward.  For more information, see an in-depth discussion here: http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/bd8f5734dc64117a

Sharding can help with scaling out, but bear in mind that you will need to run everything through a mongos process, have config servers and that the mongos will need to finalize the result sets returned from each shard, so you add a new potential bottleneck depending on your data and you will need more than just one extra machine to have it working in a reliable manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is the connections between different data items that is most valuable to them (they let the public do the work of categorising the data to make it valuable) and hence also the most dangerous to you http://indresult.com